# perl tar file extraction

Tags: perl, tar, extract

does anyone know if perl has a simple tar extraction utility like python does. if so can they provide a simple example of the extraction power. I am hoping to find a core library but a library from an external source will do

Comment: What happened when you typed "perl tar" in your favorite search engine's search box? Did nothing at all come up?

Comment: I found a bunch of external libraries I really wanted a core library

Comment: CPAN isn't an external source. :) http://search.cpan.org/search?query=tar

Comment: As far as I know there is no good tar module for Perl. The only one I have found is Archive::Tar which loads the entire file into ram. Archive::Extract looked promising until I realised it is just a wrapper for Archive::Tar. That just leaves command line. I was hoping to stream the files and use almost no memory. Yet again Perl disappoints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amongst many other modules, you can use:

- [Archive::Tar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive%3A%3ATar)

You can look at the [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-A.html) documentation to find that this is a core module in Perl, so it should always be available.  There are related packages also listed there, and you can search on http://search.cpan.org/ for more if that doesn't suit you for some reason.

---

You can also find documentation for it on [MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Tar) (which it appears [amon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon) prefers as a source of information).

You can also find listed as a core module [Archive::Extract](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Extract.html).

I've not needed to use any of these so I can't comment on the memory usage issue mentioned by [MikeKulls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944636/mikekulls).

Comment: Archive::Tar is largely useless because it uses massive amounts of ram. I can't believe this is a core module!!

Answer (score 3):

While you can use Archive::Tar, there really isn't much reason not to use the (also core) [Archive::Extract](http://p3rl.org/Archive%3a%3aExtract) which is a much more general library. That way, when you suddenly have to allow using zipped files or other formats, your code "just works".